# obtaining and updating a value in xml using elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've an xml file and i want to use ElementTree in Python 3.4 to update a value in it. I'm sticking with ElementTree to be consistent with other code.

The file looks like:

```
<Details>
    <Attrib name="Name">bill</Attrib>
    <Attrib name="Email">bill.jones@mail.com</Attrib>
    <Attrib name="Phone">555-000-555</Attrib>
</Details>

 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
 root = tree.getroot()
      for child in root:
          print("Tag: {0} Attrib: {1}".format(child.tag, child.attrib))
```

The Output of this is:

```
Tag: Attrib Attrib: {'name': 'Name'}
Tag: Attrib Attrib: {'name': 'Email'}
Tag: Attrib Attrib: {'name': 'Phone'}
```

How do I get the value of 'Phone'. So I want to get '555-000-555 and update this to another value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update value of a certain node `Attrib` which has attribute `[@name="Phone"]`, short solution:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

phone = root.find('Attrib[@name="Phone"]')
phone.text = '777-000-777'

print(ET.dump(root))    # ET.dump() - This function should be used for debugging only.
```

The output:

```
<Details>
    <Attrib name="Name">bill</Attrib>
    <Attrib name="Email">bill.jones@mail.com</Attrib>
    <Attrib name="Phone">777-000-777</Attrib>
</Details>
```

Comment: Thanks. tree.write('file.xml') completes the job by writing out the new file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`text`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text) property:

```
xmlstr = '''<Details>
    <Attrib name="Name">bill</Attrib>
    <Attrib name="Email">bill.jones@mail.com</Attrib>
    <Attrib name="Phone">555-000-555</Attrib>
</Details>'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
for child in root:
    child.text += ' (changed)'
    print("Tag: {0} text: {1}".format(child.tag, child.text))
```

This will output:

```
Tag: Attrib text: bill (changed)
Tag: Attrib text: bill.jones@mail.com (changed)
Tag: Attrib text: 555-000-555 (changed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "child.text", for example:

print(child.attrib + ": " + child.text)